# Why do I get a series inside an apply/assign function in pandas. Want to use each value to look up a dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a dict of countries and population:

```
population_dict = {"Germany": 1111, .... }
```

In my df (`sort_countries`) I have a column called 'country' and I want to add another column called 'population' from the dictionary above (matching 'country' with 'population'):

```
population_df = sort_countries.assign(
    population=lambda x: population_dict[x["country"]], axis = 1)
population_df.head()
```

which gives the error: `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`.

Why is `x["country"]` a Series when I would imagine it should return just the name of the country.

This bit of pandas always confuses me. In my lambdas I would expect x to be a row and I just select the country from that row. Instead len(x["country"]) gives me 192 (the number of my countries, the whole Series).

How else can I match them using lambdas and not a separate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `x["country"]` is a `Series`, albeit a single element one, this cannot be used to index the dictionary. If you want just the value associated with it, use `x["country"].item()`.

However, a better approach tailor made for this kind of thing is using `df.map`:

```
population_df["population"] = population_df["country"].map(population_dict)
```

`map` will automatically map keys taken from population_df["country"] and map them to their appropriate values in `population_dict`.

Comment: the map one works perfectly. But the .item() doesn't. I believe x["country"] is a series with the whole column. Don't understand why. I just need that specific row...

Answer (score 0):

Also:

`population_df["population"] = population_df.apply(lambda x: population_dict[x["country"]], axis=1)`

works. 
Or:

```
population_df["population"] = population_df[["country"]].applymap(lambda x: population_dict[x])
```